# Access 2010 - VBA - Editing underlying table data using text boxes on a form

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010

I'm using too many boolean indicators and I'm sure its very inefficient/stupid...

Currently in the Access database I have numerous forms which are used to edit underlying records. Text boxes on these forms are not bound to the underlying table. I do not wish to bind the form or any of its controls directly to the underlying tables, if the data is editable by the user (less human error from users). Instead I've a Boolean for every control which contains editable information.

Users enter 'edit mode', change information (Boolean now equals true), click 'save changes', review the changes and accept and then the relevant queries are run to reflect these changes. I like this order of events however, I'm creating increasingly complex forms with 40 or so editable controls and hence 40 Boolean variables.

Anyone think of an nicer alternative? Is there a property of the controls (mainly text boxes) I can use?

CODE:
    Private Sub CommentsText_AfterUpdate()

```
    If Nz(Me.CommentsText) = "" Then
        CommentsEdit = False
    Else
        CommentsEdit = True
    End If
End Sub

    'Within the 'save changes' method
    If CommentsEdit Then
        CommentsEdit = False
        sql = "Update [General-CN] Set [Comments] = '" & Left(Me.CommentsText, 250) & "' Where [ID ( G )] = " & Me.[GeneralPK] & ";"
        DoCmd.RunSQL (sql)
    End If
```

Comment: Reason to why you do not want to use Bound Forms? Access is not actually built to work with unbound forms.

Comment: To give me more control over the users actions (data validation primarily).

Answer (score 0):

normally data validation during data entry is one the things that normally, in my experience, before or later put the developer on his knees.

From your question, I can feel that the core is to preserve database integrity. Unfortunately there is no way to ABSOLUTELY preserve your database. If you give access to it to users you can only use some tips:

1 - If possible use combo-box with defined entries instead of using textboxes in which user is free to digit anything (e.g. think an expert system that collect data about the same problem written in many different ways!!!)

2 - Check data integrity and coherence (e.g. type) before writing it to database

3 - When the data is just a boolean (flag) you can use switches, radio button or checkboxes.

These tips help in developing a user interface more friendly and faster from the point of view of data entry.

After this I can give you another way to validate your data. 
If you want to show data to user before saving you can create the mask in which you enter your data with unbounded textboxes. 
Then, when he clicks the Save Button, you can show a 2nd form, opened in append mode, in which you show data with textboxes bounded to your db.

If he accepts the data, you can save otherwise you can cancel the data entry preserving your database. I post you here some lines of code with an example taken from an application of mine. It's the part in which I manage contacts

The form allows to input contact data

```
'------------------------------------------------------
' Temp variables to store entries before saving /cancelling
'------------------------------------------------------
Dim bolValidationErr As Boolean

Dim m_vntLastName As Variant
Dim m_vntFirstName As Variant
Dim m_vntFC As Variant
Dim m_vntVATNum As Variant
Dim m_vntAddress As Variant
Dim m_vntCity As Variant
Dim m_vntZIP As Variant
Dim m_vntCountry As Variant
Dim m_vntPhone As Variant
Dim m_vntFAX As Variant
Dim m_vntEMail As Variant
Dim m_vntNote As Variant
Dim m_vntContactType As Variant

'------------------------------------------------------
' Suppress error "Impossible to save the record...
'------------------------------------------------------
Private Sub Form_Error(DataErr As Integer, Response As Integer)
    If DataErr = 2169 Then
        Response = True
    End If
End Sub

'------------------------------------------------------
' W/o customer last name, cancel saving
'------------------------------------------------------
Private Sub Form_Beforeupdate(Cancel As Integer)
On Error GoTo Err_Form_BeforeUpdate
    Dim strType As String
    Dim bolNewContact As Boolean
    Dim intErrFC As Integer
    Dim intErrVATNum As Integer
    Dim intErrFullName As Integer
    Dim strErrMsg As String
    Dim intAnswer As Integer

    bolValidationErr = False

    '------------------------------------------------------
    ' If LastName is missing, cancel data saving
    ' Cancel = True cause the raise of the error 
    ' "You can't save record at this time..."
    ' SetWarnings doesn't work. It's needed to intercept with Form_Error event
    '------------------------------------------------------
    If HasNoValue(Me.txtLastName) Then
        strErrMsg = "Put here your error msg"
        intAnswer = MsgBox(strErrMsg, vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, "Entry Error")
        Cancel = True                   ' Cancel db update
        Call BackupCurrentData          ' Store data input until now          
        bolValidationErr = True         ' Unvalid data
        Exit Sub
    End If

Exit_Form_BeforeUpdate:
    Exit Sub

Err_Form_BeforeUpdate:
    GoTo Exit_Form_BeforeUpdate

End Sub

'------------------------------------------------------
' Store the content of textboxes for restoring them in case
' of cancelling
'------------------------------------------------------
' If the record is new, if the BeforeUpdate event is cancelled, 
' NULL values are restored (in fact there were no data!!!)
'------------------------------------------------------
Private Sub BackupCurrentData()
    m_vntLastName = Me.txtLastName
    m_vntFirstName = Me.txtFirstName
    m_vntFC = Me.txtFC
    m_vntVATNum = Me.txtVATNum
    m_vntAddress = Me.txtAddress
    m_vntCity = Me.txtCity
    m_vntZIP = Me.txtZIP
    m_vntCountry = Me.txtCountry
    m_vntPhone = Me.txtTelNum
    m_vntFAX = Me.txtFax
    m_vntEMail = Me.txtEmail
    m_vntNote = Me.txtNotes
    m_vntContactType = Me.cmbContactType

End Sub

'------------------------------------------------------
' Restore contents of textboxes before cancelling operation
'------------------------------------------------------
Private Sub RestoreCurrentData()
    Me.txtLastName = m_vntLastName
    Me.txtFirstName = m_vntFirstName
    Me.txtFC = m_vntFC
    Me.txtVATNum = m_vntVATNum
    Me.txtAddress = m_vntAddress
    Me.txtCity = m_vntCity
    Me.txtZIP = m_vntZIP
    Me.txtCountry = m_vntCountry
    Me.txtTelNum = m_vntPhone
    Me.txtFax = m_vntFAX
    Me.txtEmail = m_vntEMail
    Me.txtNotes = m_vntNote
    Me.cmbContactType = m_vntContactType
End Sub
```

I think that this code can be adapted to your needs.
The variable names are enough self-describing
Anyway feel free to contact me if you need further help.

Bye,

Wiz:-)

Comment: Excellent suggestions. Thank you for your time, I'll use these.